# Select-Object list of properties from a variable

Tags: powershell

I am trying to analyze a lot of `robocopy` logs to have summaries in column instead of lines.

I gather data in an array of hashes which works fine. Each hash has the following structure:

```
Bytes_Copied   : 0
Bytes_FAILED   : 0
Source         : PROGRAM
Files_Total    : 582794
```

I am exporting them like that:

```
Bytes_Copied    Bytes_FAILED   Source      Files_Total   
------------    ------------   ------      -----------   
      1.006t           1.69m     TEAM           884194
```

As I want to export them into a CSV I wish I was able to select the order of columns. This works when I "hard code" properties in the command:

```psh
$collectLines | Select-Object -Property Source,Date,Started,Ended,BpSec |
  Where-Object {$_.Source -eq 'TEAM'} |
  Export-Csv $ExportFileTeam -NoTypeInformation
```

As there are many more columns actually I had the idea to put them in a string to help choosing the order without touching code that works.

```psh
$ExportList = "Source,Date,Started,Ended,BpSec"
```

But I cannot make it to have the Select-Object take care of my string:

```psh
Select-Object -Property $ExportList
```

I tried many things with parentheses, braces, nothing works. Also I could not find a clue on the Internet.

Comment: `"Source,Date,Started,Ended,BpSec"` is *one* string, `Select-Object -Property` expects one string *per* property: `$ExportList = "Source","Date","Started","Ended","BpSec"`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You must specify the property list as an array of strings, not as a single string with comma-separated names:

```
$ExportList = 'Source', 'Date', 'Started', 'Ended', 'BpSec'
```

Comment: That's it.. blushing for having missed that